# subset data.frame for every level of a factor

Tags: r

Given the following vectors to build a dataframe :

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE)
y <- runif(100,0,100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

I would like to have if possible, a clean code with a loop or `apply` or any other method to subset the `data.frame` by different conditionals for every level of factor `x`. For example:

```
level A  y >30 | y <20
level B  y >21 | y <12
level C  y >42 | y <21
level D  y >58 | y <13
```

Comment: Do you mean `|` ( OR ) instead of `&` ( AND ) by any chance?

Comment: yep. sorry I meant `|`

Comment: This can be implemented as a combination of `cut()`, to change y to a categorical, then a [tag:split-apply-combine] using dplyr/tidyr or data.table.

Comment: The nuance here is that some levels have two non-contiguous bins, and the order in which you bin things makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A split apply combine approach where we use `Map` to iterate over the subsets and the conditions in parallel.

```
do.call(rbind,
        Map(function(data, left, right) {
          subset(x = data, subset = y > left | y < right) 
          },
          data = split(df, df$x),
          left = c(30, 21, 42, 58),
          right = c(20, 12, 21, 13)
        ))
#      x         y
#A.5   A 63.349326
#A.10  A 59.876097
#A.11  A 97.617069
#A.12  A 73.179251
#A.22  A 49.559358
#A.24  A 17.344233
# ...
```

We split your data by `x`, subset each according to your conditions and combine the list to a single dataframe.

Comment: this is nice ! thanks for sharing, I will learn a lot form this code

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
df[df$x == 'A' & (df$y > 30 | df$y < 20),]
#    x         y
# 2  A 71.117606
# 3  A 44.438057
# 6  A 63.244699
# 7  A 54.185802
# 11 A 39.577617
# 13 A  8.681545
# 29 A 94.437431
# ...
# or depending on what you mean by '&'
df[df$x == 'A' & df$y > 30,]
#    x        y
# 2  A 71.11761
# 3  A 44.43806
# 6  A 63.24470
# 7  A 54.18580
# 11 A 39.57762
# 29 A 94.43743
# 31 A 54.17604
# ...

# and then accordingly for the other cases
```

Answer (score 0):

using `library(data.table)` we can do

```
lower = c(20, 12, 21, 13)
upper = c(30, 21, 42, 58)
setDT(df)[!between(y, lower[x], upper[x]), .SD, keyby=x]

#    x         y
# 1: A 63.349326
# 2: A 59.876097
# 3: A 97.617069
# 4: A 73.179251
# 5: A 49.559358
# 6: A 17.344233
# 7: A 51.116978
# ...
```